# Button not change to disabled when dialog appear again in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem with the `disabled` property of a button in ASP page. It only happens in IE 11 and is OK in other browsers.

These are my action steps before the problem appears:

1: I click the download button and a dialog appears. I check 2 check-boxes in it to enable the button download. Then I click the same download button and the file is saved .

2: I click again on the download button and the dialog appears. But now the button is still enabled and the check-boxes are unchecked. However when I move the mouse pointer over the download button , it immediately changes to disabled.

Expected behaviour: when I open the download dialog again the button must be disabled.

Here is my code:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function () {
    if ( $("#checkbox_1").is(":checked") && $("#checkbox_2").is(":checked") ) {
        $("#download_button").removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $("#download_button").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Thanks all.

Comment: try to do `$("#download_button").mouseover()` programmatically if you don't get a proper solution...

Comment: hi Sami , 
My expectation: when i open download dialog again download button must be disabled
Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the checkboxes it will disable the button. When you download a new dialog box you are downloading a new non disabled button. You have to run your code again after the dialog has been downloaded to re-disable the button, to do that In the dialog's code you want to add:

```
<script>

    if ($("#checkbox_1").is(":checked") && $("#checkbox_2").is(":checked"))
        $("#download_button").removeAttr('disabled');
    else
        $("#download_button").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Rolyataylor,
i run my code on IE11 then using debug to watch property disabled of download button . i see that when i click on download button and dialog show again , button download has been set to disable (i mean disabled="disabled") . So i think that problem not from jquery it may be from CSS . Do you have any idea for me !!! 
Thanks !

Comment: and this problem just happen in IE11 . in other browsers it's ok !!! i don't know why

Comment: I have read elsewhere that people are having this issue. They had to redefine the disabled css code to get it to look disabled. "input[disabled],input:disabled, input[disabled="disabled"]{
     /* Styles to target disabled <input> elements here */
}"

Comment: Does the button act like it is disabled and just look like it is not disabled?

Comment: just look like it is not disabled .
actually , i have a page this page contain a button name 'download' . when i click on this button a dialog download is showed. dialog have a button , it also name 'download' , this button is set disabled="disabled" . if i check on 2 check box  then this button is set disable=" "; then i cancel dialog. click again on button download ( on page , not on dialog) dialog show again , button download (on dialog) it look like not disabled , but when move mouse's point to this button , this button immediately disabled. 
I don't know why !!!
Thanks